# Last character of a Tamil unicode string

Tags: vb.net, unicode-string

How to get the last character of a unicode tamil string.
for example i am having a list of strings like `"சுதீப்", "செய்தியை", "கொள்ளாதது", "வில்லன்"`

if i use mystring.Last() for the above strings
i am getting

"சுதீப்" = `""்""`
"செய்தியை" = `"ை`
"கொள்ளாதது" = `""ு""`
"வில்லன்" = `""்""`

but i need to get

"சுதீப்" = `""ப்""`
"செய்தியை" = `""யை""`
"கொள்ளாதது" = `""து""`
"வில்லன்" = `""ன்""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you create a helper function where you loop through each char and examine the [UnicodeCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**Extension**

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Module StringExtensions

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function Split(str As String, category As UnicodeCategory) As IList(Of String)
        Dim list As New List(Of String)
        If ((Not str Is Nothing) AndAlso (str.Length > 0)) Then
            Dim item As String = Nothing
            Dim chr As Char = Nothing
            For Each chr In str
                If (Char.GetUnicodeCategory(chr) = category) Then
                    If ((Not item Is Nothing) AndAlso (item.Length > 0)) Then
                        list.Add(item)
                    End If
                    item = chr
                Else
                    item += chr
                End If
            Next
            If ((Not item Is Nothing) AndAlso (item.Length > 0)) Then
                list.Add(item)
            End If
        End If
        Return list
    End Function

End Module
```

**Usage**

```
Imports [your_namespace].StringExtensions

Dim values As String() = {"சுதீப்", "செய்தியை", "கொள்ளாதது", "வில்லன்"}
Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

For Each item As String In values
    builder.AppendLine(String.Concat(item, " : ", item.Split(UnicodeCategory.OtherLetter).Last()))
Next

MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString())
```

**Output**

```
சுதீப் : ப்
செய்தியை : யை
கொள்ளாதது : து
வில்லன் : ன்
```