# Last two or three character of a Tamil unicode string

Tags: vb.net, unicode-string

How to get the last two or three character of a unicode tamil string. for example i am having a list of strings like "சுதீப்", "செய்தியை", "கொள்ளாதது", "வில்லன்"

i need to get

```
"சுதீப்" = ""தீப்"" 
"செய்தியை" = ""தியை"" 
"கொள்ளாதது" = ""தது"" 
"வில்லன்" = ""ல்லன்""
```

Comment: Please check this link it might help you brother.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316861/last-character-of-a-tamil-unicode-string.

Comment: I want for last two and three characters

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your desired programming language. Still, in VB.NET you can separate them and get it using the String.Substring() function. This is also applicable to C#.

For example:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal e As EventArgs, ByVal sender as Object) Handles Button1.Click
MsgBox(TextBox1.Text.Substring({Character Index},{Character Count})
End Sub
```

In the above code, you must change the character index and count as you want.

Normally in Tamil Character Map, "Uyirmei" characters are formed by a combination of "Uyir" and "Mei" characters, i.e: கீதை is formed by ௧+ீ+த+ை, a total of four characters.

I hope that you can understand this!